# How to express that a set is closed under an operation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I want to express following sentence in mathematical notation

> The set $\mathcal{R}$ is closed under conjunction (i.e., $\wedge$)

I have these ideas:

$\forall r_1, r_2 \in \mathcal{R} \Rightarrow r_1 \wedge r_2 \in \mathcal{R}$

Or maybe

$ r_1 \wedge r_2 \text{ for every } r_1,r_2 \in \mathcal{R} $

Is any of them acceptable? Do you have another idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is sufficient, the second one is not.  The second will be sufficient if you change it to: $$r_{1}\wedge r_{2} \in \mathcal{R} \forall r_{1},r_{2}\in \mathcal{R}$$

Comment: Good, so I was in the right track. Thanks.